# Does anybody have suggestions for how you would tackle this problem in OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to find the Australian Aboriginal flag in a collection of historic artwork.

Aboriginal Flag: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4ncb.png

Example Artworks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvHgg.jpg

I am new to OpenCV but have been programming for a long time.

I am confident I can code the solution but I can't seem to figure out what an easier solution would look like.

Should I;

- Gray scale, find contours, find circles that exist inside rectangles where the area of the circle is a certain percentage area of the rectangle?
- Find red, yellow, black shapes that have close proximity?
- Gray scale, find circles that exist in rectangles. Then check if the circle is yellow in the original?

Anyone have any cool ideas on how to make this easy?

I plan on running this over 2.8 million images ahaha

My original reason is here -> https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24187794

Comment: What about template matching? Official OpenCV tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html. 
 Also an answer here from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990259/template-matching-using-opencv-in-python

Comment: With the degree of distortion in flags and color changes, I suspect you will need to train a solution with deep learning

Comment: @rayryeng That looks super helpful, I didn't see that feature, thank you very much.